# Ajax script not working on CakePhp form

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So i have this code in my add.ctp action and i want it to load another div after submiting this form, but since im farly new to CakePHP3 and Ajax i can't figure out what makes the script not work, the jQuery on my page works fine but the logs inside the script don't show up in the console.I might be missing something very obvious but I ask for your anwsers.

```
      <?php
      echo $this->Form->create($article, ['id' => 'ajaxform']);
      echo $this->Form->input('title',array('class'=`enter code here`>'form-control'));
      echo $this->Form->input('body', ['rows' => '3','class'=>'form-control']);
      echo '<p></p>';
      echo $this->Form->button(__('Salvar artigo'),array('class'=>'btn btn-success', 'id' => 'butao'));
      echo $this->Form->end();
      ?>


      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log("test");
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#butao').click(function(e){
          console.log("teste2");
          $("#ajaxform").submit();
          e.preventDefault;
            $(".content-wrapper").load("main #main");
        });

        $("#ajaxform").on('submit',function(e)
        {
          console.log("teste");
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                  $('#main').html(data);
                    //data: return data from server
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    //if fails
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
            e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
        });

        $("#ajaxform").submit(); //Submit  the FORM


      });
      </script>
```

ArticlesController:

```
public function add()
{
    $article = $this->Articles->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData());
        // Added this line
        $article->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        // You could also do the following
        //$newData = ['user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')];
        //$article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $newData);
        if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'main']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your article.'));
    }
    $this->set('article', $article);
}
```

--EDIT--
My Main page code which goes to add

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
  <tr>
      <td><?= $article->id ?></td>
      <td>
          <?= $this->Html->link($article->title, ['action' => 'view', 
$article->id]) ?>
      </td>
      <td>
          <?= $article->created->format(DATE_RFC850) ?>
      </td>
      <td>
            <?= $this->Form->postLink(
                'Apagar',
                ['action' => 'delete', $article->id],
                ['confirm' => 'Têm a certeza?','class'=>'btn-danger btn-sm'])

            ?>
          <?= $this->Html->link('Editar', ['action' => 'edit', $article->id],array('class'=>'btn-warning btn-sm')) ?>
          <?= $this->Html->link('Copiar', ['action' => 'copy', $article->id],array('class'=>'btn-warning btn-sm')) ?>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</div>
<button id="add" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
    <h6>Adicionar Artigo</h6>
    <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#add').click(function(){
          $("#main").load("add #addctp");
      });
    });
    </script>
  </button>
```

Comment: Where is your form action?

Comment: In my controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a json from your controller.

For that:

In `app/Config/routes.php` add:

```
Router::extensions(['json']);
```

to enable the json extension.

In your controller add:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}
```

to enable automatic view class switching on content types.

Change `$this->set('article', $article);` to:

```
$this->set(compact('article'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['article']);
```

This lets you skip defining view files for your controller actions if you don’t need to do any custom formatting before your data is converted into `json/xml`.

Now you can request `ArticlesController::add()` with json extension, then your action will serialize `$article` as json.

Finally create `app/webroot/js/Articles.js`:

```
Articles = {
    init: function () {
        this.add();
    },

    add: function(){
        $( "#ajaxform" ).submit(function( event ) {

            var that    = $(this),
                data    = that.serializeArray(),
                formURL = $('#ajaxform').attr('action') + '.json';

            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax(
            {
                url: formURL,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function(data,text,xhr)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function()
                {

                },
                complete: function ()
                {

                }
            });


        });
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    Articles.init();
});
```

and include in your view:

```
<?= $this->Html->script('Articles', ['block' => true]); ?>
```

See also:

- [Enabling data views in your application](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#enabling-data-views-in-your-application)
- [Using data views with the serialize key](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key)
- [Routing File Extensions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions)

Comment: I don't know if it is because of CakePHP3 but Router::parseExtensions('json'); gives Error: Call to undefined method Cake\Routing\Router::parseExtensions() and puts the code in Infinite loop.

Comment: Sorry, I have writen the answer for CakePHP 2.x, I will update.

Comment: $this->set('_serialize', ['article'])); syntax error in parentesis and if i take it off it gives me Error: Cannot unset string offsets.

Comment: @DanielPereira fixed

Comment: Add your actual code as part of the question signaling as an edit

Comment: @Rayann_Nayran Code works, but the  script still doesn't.

Comment: After i click submit it makes me reload the page still

Comment: Make sure the script is loaded and the function is being called.

Comment: I know script are called with $this->html->script('Articles.js'); but i don't know where to call the function (i'm very new to these languages)

Comment: `Articles.add()` function is called automatically when the page is loaded. Add some `alert()` to debug the `Articles.js`

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm using the alert right but i put alert('test'); right after 2nd <script> and the box isn't showing up

Comment: You should create the file and not using `<script>` tag

Comment: Ok, so move all code inside <script> tag to a file and call it?

Comment: unfortunatly i cannot move this to chat since i don't have enough rep but i would need a bit babysitting trough this